# How to scan a List<String>

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method in java that will use a scanner to read a List String. I want the program to divide the array word by word using the delineator "//s". I already got each array by the names of the people in the text file, I am just trying to divide the array further so that way i can sort them by there information (Ex. if they have f for female I would be able to call that specific part of the array using arrayList.get(index) and sort it by gender that way) Here is my code:

Sorry for being unclear, here is my full code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;



public class Filereader {

public static void replaceSlash(List<String> array) {



    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
      {
        if (array.get(i).contains("-")) 
        {
            array.set(i, array.get(i).replace("-", "/"));
        }
      }

}

public static void split( List<String> array ) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner().useDelimiter("\\s");
    for (int i= 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            array.set(i, scanner.next());
        }

    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    System.out.println("Please type the name of the file you wish to sort: ");
    //get the name of the file
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    File fileName = new File(scanner.nextLine());

    scanner = new Scanner(fileName).useDelimiter("\\s");
    List<String> annaK = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> martinaH = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> monicaS = new ArrayList<String>();


    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        annaK.add(scanner.nextLine());
        martinaH.add(scanner.nextLine());
        monicaS.add(scanner.nextLine());


    }



    replaceSlash(annaK);
    replaceSlash(martinaH);
    replaceSlash(monicaS);

    split(annaK);



    System.out.println(annaK);
    System.out.println(martinaH);
    System.out.println(monicaS);

}
}
```

Comment: Can you give us valid inputs and outputs?  I think you're going about this incorrectly.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do. Please elaborate.

Comment: Your list should **already be** "divided words"

Answer (score 1):

You can make one scanner for every string within the list, then loop over that

```
for (String a : array) {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(a).useDelimiter("\\s");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }

}
```

However, `a.split()`  or `StringTokenizer` make more sense than a Scanner here

Besides that, `array.set` won't work because you're assigning the same `i` value for multiple words within each individual `a` value... Which will result in only the last value in the scanned string to be assigned to that index of the list

If you're trying to splits all words within a list into a **new** list, then you'll actually need to create and append values to a separate list object (don't modify your parameters, and don't have methods with side effects)